# RadioButton not getting initialised

Tags: android, radio-button, swipe

I am currently developing an app to convert values from one number system to another.
I have defined some code which allows the user to set his/her 'favorite' conversion.

The following code reads stored value of 'conversion from' and 'conversion to' and sets the corresponding fragment in the swipe-view. Also the corresponding RadioButton in the fragment is checked:
(updated code):

```
 public void putFav() {
    RadioButton b1,b2,b3;
    String from=prefs.getString("from", "--");
    String to=prefs.getString("to", "--");
    if(from.contentEquals("Binary"))
    {
        b1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.bToD);
        b2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.bToO);
        b3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.bToH);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        BinFragment ob=new BinFragment();
        ob.onCreateView(getLayoutInflater(), mViewPager, mCollectionPagerAdapter.args);
        if(to.contentEquals("Decimal"))
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), String.valueOf(ob.DecButton.getId())+" "+String.valueOf(ob.OctButton.getId())+" "+String.valueOf(ob.HexButton.getId())+" ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            b1.setChecked(true);
            b2.setChecked(false);
            b3.setChecked(false);
        }
        if(to.contentEquals("Octal"))
        {

            b1.setChecked(false);
            b2.setChecked(true);
            b3.setChecked(false);
        }
        if(to.contentEquals("Hexadecimal"))
        {

            b1.setChecked(false);
            b2.setChecked(false);
            b3.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
    else if(from.contentEquals("Decimal"))
    {
        b1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.dToB);
        b2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.dToO);
        b3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.dToH);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        DecFragment ob=new DecFragment();
        ob.onCreateView(getLayoutInflater(), mViewPager, mCollectionPagerAdapter.args);
        if(to.contentEquals("Binary"))
        {
            b1.setChecked(true);
            b2.setChecked(false);
            b3.setChecked(false);

        }
        if(to.contentEquals("Octal"))
        {

            b1.setChecked(false);
            b2.setChecked(true);
            b3.setChecked(false);
        }
        if(to.contentEquals("Hexadecimal"))
        {
            b1.setChecked(false);
            b2.setChecked(false);
            b3.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
    else if(from.contentEquals("Octal"))
    {
        b1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.oToB);
        b2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.oToD);
        b3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.oToH);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        OctFragment ob=new OctFragment();
        ob.onCreateView(getLayoutInflater(), mViewPager, mCollectionPagerAdapter.args);
        if(to.contentEquals("Decimal"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), String.valueOf(ob.BinButton.getId())+" "+String.valueOf(ob.DecButton.getId())+" "+String.valueOf(ob.HexButton.getId())+" ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /*b1.setChecked(false);
            b2.setChecked(true);
            b3.setChecked(false);*/
        }
        if(to.contentEquals("Binary"))
        {

            b1.setChecked(true);
            b2.setChecked(false);
            b3.setChecked(false);
        }
        if(to.contentEquals("Hexadecimal"))
        {

            b1.setChecked(false);
            b2.setChecked(false);
            b3.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
    else if(from.contentEquals("Hexadecimal"))
    {

        b1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.hToB);
        b2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.hToO);
        b3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.hToD);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
        HexFragment ob=new HexFragment();
        ob.onCreateView(getLayoutInflater(), mViewPager, mCollectionPagerAdapter.args);
        if(to.contentEquals("Decimal"))
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), String.valueOf(ob.BinButton.getId())+" "+String.valueOf(ob.OctButton.getId())+" "+String.valueOf(ob.DecButton.getId())+" ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            b1.setChecked(false);
            b2.setChecked(false);
            b3.setChecked(true);
        }
        if(to.contentEquals("Octal"))
        {

            b1.setChecked(false);
            b2.setChecked(true);
            b3.setChecked(false);
        }
        if(to.contentEquals("Binary"))
        {

            b1.setChecked(true);
            b2.setChecked(false);
            b3.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Favourites Not Declared. Settings->Set Favourite Conversion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

The problem I encounter is that in the "Binary" and "decimal" if-statements the RadioButtons are being initialised correctly and the code works, but in the "Octal" and "Hexadecimal" part the RadioButtons are not being initialised even when that code is being executed. All the id's are correct, I have cross-checked them.
This is the layout.xml for one of the fragments (octal) from the swipe-view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".OctFragment" 
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/oct_msg"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:digits="01234567."
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:text="@string/convert_msg"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/oToB"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="@string/binary" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/oToD"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/oToB"
    android:layout_below="@+id/oToB"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="@string/decimal" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/oToH"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/oToD"
    android:layout_below="@+id/oToD"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="@string/hexa" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_below="@+id/oToH"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/convert" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="@string/equals"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:hint="@string/null_string"
    android:text="@string/null_string"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

If anyone knows the fix, or the problem causing factor, please do reply. :)

And I'm still learning Java programming, so excuse me if the code is inefficient and kiddish.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: `b1=(RadioButton)findViewById(2131296268);` **NEVER** hard-code view ids like that. Use a value from `R.id.<your view id here>` instead. The integer values often change, using a value from `R.id.` will make sure it's correct.

Comment: Post your .xml layout file and use the ids from the layout.

Comment: You say that "in the "Octal" and "Hexadecimal" part the RadioButtons are not being initialised", so I have to ask: What happens when you run that part of the code? Does the application crash? Does it just not show anything on your activity? Because if the application **does not** crash and it seems like nothing happens, then they are initialized, they're just initialized to a RadioButton that is currently not visible.

Comment: Yes the app crashes. On debugging for errors I noticed that the RadioButton variables remain 'null'

Comment: How has the process been going for you with this question? Any news? Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Hey yes I sorted it out myself. The problem was that the view itself was not getting initialised. So i just switched a few statements and called setCurrentItem() first and then initialised the buttons. That worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the same ids in your Binary, Decimal, Octal and Hexadecimal code. Which is why I refuse to believe that `All the id's are correct`. You will have to change your code according to my suggestion below, show me your layout.xml, R.java, and then I will believe that the hard coded id-values is not the problem.

So I say again:

**NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER EVER** (I'm sorry but I really can't emphasize this enough) hard-code view ids like that. Use a value from R.id. instead. The integer values often change, using a value from R.id. will make sure it's correct. If you refer to the `R.id.` values in your code, I am sure that it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your interest.
I had first used the identifier tags in place of the values, but I thought that may be a problem so changed that temporarily. But the same problem persists.
I think it has something to do with the if-else-if ladder logic. As the 'decimal' code works perfect but the later two codes don't.

Comment: Edit your question with the updated code and add your layout.xml and I can see.

Comment: I have updated my question with the changed code and layout file for one of the fragments(the one giving the problem)